# MQ Server Connection Channel Configuration via MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq, channel

I have a MQ Server setup in windows . I have a client application program which connects to this server. 
I have created a QManager using my MQ explorer 7.1 .
 Created the local queues . 
Created the Server Connection Channel with MCA as * ( for all users).
Created the Client Connection Channel - with QManager name , Connection name as [hostname(port)] ,

The problem here is that on checking the Server COnnection Channel Status , it is always showing as Inactive . 
Tried using a sample client program to connect to MQ Server but it gave 2058 error.

I am not sure if I have created the Connection Channels successfully or not. 
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a server-connection channel (SVRCONN) is the correct type. However MCAUSER set as * will cause you problems once you manage to connect. Your SVRCONN channel must be named to match what you supplied in the MQSERVER environment variable.

If you are using the MQSERVER environment variable then the CLNTCONN channel wasn't needed. It is used to build a CCDT.

The channel status will only show as running once you manage to connect.

Make sure you started a listener on the same port as you put in the MQSERVER environment variable.

Comment: Could you please point to a blog / doc that clearly states the steps required to connecting a channel from java. With ibm online doc windows OS is not covered properly.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030690_.htm

Comment: If I wanna connect to 2 channels one by one in single java program how to do the MQSERVER environment variable.

Comment: 2 different channels cannot be represented by a single MQSERVER environment variable. Your question sounds rather different than the one you are posting against, perhaps you can start a new question with some more details about what you are trying to do and we can answer it for you in detail?

Answer (score 1):

So 2058 is MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR.. so the client code has made a connection but the QueueManager name the application supplied isn't the same as the QueueManager that 'answered'

That's the first place to check... what is the sample application?  MQI, Java classes, JMS classes?

It might be the app is connecting in bindings i.e. not using the network at all.. How have you configured the client?

Matthew

Comment: I am using a sample amqsput0.c provided along with MQ installation from unix machine to connect to this Server in windows.
From Client application , I am exporting the values of MQSERVER=CHANNEL1/TCP/hostname(port). I have some doubts regarding the Server channel connection created at MQ Server end. For a c program to connect to this MQ what are the pre-requistes at server end . Do we create Server-Connection Channel(MQI) or create server-receiver channels . I am not able to verify if the server connection channel created is proper as the status is showing as Inactive.